# How much time to hear back after a UK academic interview?

Tags: united-kingdom, interview, lecturer

From your experience, how soon did you hear back from an academic interview in the UK? The Department with which I had an interview for a lecturer role said that they needed to appoint someone asap but it has been three days I haven't heard back so I just wanted to hear about others' experiences.

**Update:** I have heard back from the department and sadly I wasn't successful. Thanks all for your helpful comments.

Comment: Likely they are interviewing a few people. Three days seems short.

Comment: @Buffy > *Likely they are interviewing a few people.* --- no, this is unlikely. In the UK, the final interviews for all candidates are normally scheduled in one day or two consecutive days.

Comment: One time, 1 day. Another time, 2 months that ended up being 9 months. It kinda depends. I'd say a week wait until you send them an email is reasonable.

Comment: You wrote lecturer *role*. Is this a permanent position of the academic rank lecturer or some temporary teaching contract? In any case you can always email your academic contact and ask for a timeline.

Comment: @user2705196, I believe they meant  Lecturer Role = Assistant Professor in the UK.

Answer (score 9):

In the UK, the HR Departments at most (all?) Universities are notoriously slow. They would want to see all the paperwork post-interview before they approve the new hire, and they do take their time for it.

From my personal experience in the UK:

- 1 time the Chair of the hiring committee contacted me directly and informally in 2-3 days after the interview. The decision was not yet confirmed by the HRs, and the Chair contacted me on their own risk because they knew time was of the essence for me (due to my visa situation) and they cared.
- 2 times I received a call after a week or two. I was the first candidate and the decision was pre-approved by HRs but they still wanted Chairs to contact me informally first to make sure I am going to accept before they would issue me a formal offer (if not, why bother?)
- 10+ times I was not the first candidate. The rejection letter came by email sometimes a month, sometimes 6 months after the interview.
- In a few very extreme cases, I had to chase the Department for feedback and reimbursement of my travel fees 6+ months after the interview. It was really a shame.

To summarise - in the UK, the academic hiring process for postdocs and lecturers is slow, disorganised, formalistic,  and not really friendly towards the candidate. Waiting 3+ days for the response after the interview is very common.

I have no experience and no idea how things stand for the Professors. YMMV

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your experience! Their teaching starts next week so I feel like it's unlikely that I get the job.

Comment: @Maisie The teaching assignments would have been decided months ago. So even if you did get the job it's unlikely you would be teaching this semester. I don't think you can draw any conclusions from this.

Comment: @atom44 It is not unusual to reserve a module or two for the new hire in the Department's timetable, particularly if the new post was justified by the demand in teaching.

Comment: @atom44 do you think it’s worth contacting HR to ask about the result? I’m under time pressure and need to know…

Comment: @Maisie If you need to know for a genuine time-sensitive reason, I would email your point of contact and explain the situation; at the very least they should be able to give you more clarity as to their expected timetable.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov, they may do this. But if this was the case I would hope they would interview people more than a week before the beginning of the semester! For example, hiring over the summer so they have time to prepare. But there could be semester 2 teaching already planned for the new hire.

Comment: @Maisie, I wouldn't recommend contacting HR. In fact, I don't believe that HR has relevance to your situation. The *academic* committee (possibly through the head of department secretary) is the one who'd contact you about your interview. These are you contact points. HR is still not even involved, because my estimation you have not yet been appointment or recommended. Even if recommended to be appointed you'd first here from the head of department, not HR.

Answer (score 9):

My estimation is somewhat different from Dmitry's answer.
In my opinion, the committee has selected another candidate, and is now waiting for his/her acceptance. As long as the candidate doesn't accept you are still in a waiting list, and have the chance to be contacted later (though this is unlikely in most cases).

*Comment*: in the UK, unlike the US, interviews are conducted in one or two days, to all the candidates at once.

*Comment* 2: In some rare cases interviews can be conducted like the US, and in this case you shouldn't be waiting for an answer soon.